# Старый стиль соединения таблиц в новый

Tags: sql, oracle

Был запрос другого человека:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM TABLE_1, 
       TABLE_2
  WHERE TABLE_1.COL_A = TABLE_2.COL_A(+)
```

Мне понадобилось расширить первую таблицу, приджойнив свою (даже не заметил этого плюса в скобках, когда писал).

```
SELECT ...
  FROM TABLE_1
         LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_1.COL_B = TABLE_3.COL_B, 
       TABLE_2
  WHERE TABLE_1.COL_A = TABLE_2.COL_A(+)
```

После чего словил ошибку:

> ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins

Видимо, старое и новое соединение не живут вместе. Правильно ли я понимаю, что верным решением будет:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM TABLE_1
         LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_1.COL_B = TABLE_3.COL_B 
         FULL JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.COL_A = TABLE_2.COL_A
```

Или (+) не равнозначен полному внешнему? Первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой формой записи...

Comment: (+) - это аналог `left join`. Старожилы говорят, он появился раньше, чем `left join` добавили в стандарт. Так и живем. Ну а также - [You cannot specify the (+) operator in a query block that also contains FROM clause join syntax.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354) Оффдока - наше всё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, (+) не эквивалент `FULL JOIN`. Это эквивалент `LEFT JOIN` или `RIGHT JOIN` в зависимости от порядка таблиц в запросе, `(+)` ставится со стороны той таблицы, где записей удовлетворяющих условию может не быть.
В вашем случае

```
SELECT ...
  FROM TABLE_1, 
       TABLE_2
  WHERE TABLE_1.COL_A = TABLE_2.COL_A(+)
```

равно

```
SELECT ...
  FROM TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN 
       TABLE_2
  ON TABLE_1.COL_A = TABLE_2.COL_A
```

А вот `FULL JOIN` в старой нотации выглядел бы так

```
SELECT ...
  FROM TABLE_1, 
       TABLE_2
  WHERE TABLE_1.COL_A = TABLE_2.COL_A(+)
UNION 
SELECT ...
  FROM TABLE_1, 
       TABLE_2
  WHERE TABLE_1.COL_A(+) = TABLE_2.COL_A
```

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего показать как это работает на примерах.

Исходные таблицы:

```
SQL> select * from a;

        ID       COL1
---------- ----------
         1         11
         2         12
         3         13

3 rows selected.

SQL> select * from b;

        ID       COL2
---------- ----------
         1        111
         3        333
         5        555

3 rows selected.
```

"old style" `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SQL> select * from a, b where a.id = b.id (+);

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         11          1        111
         3         13          3        333
         2         12

3 rows selected.
```

что эквивалентно *ANSI* `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SQL> select * from a left outer join b on a.id = b.id;

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         11          1        111
         3         13          3        333
         2         12

3 rows selected.
```

---

"old style" `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SQL> r
  1  select * from a, b where a.id = b.id(+)
  2  union
  3* select * from a, b where a.id(+) = b.id

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         11          1        111
         2         12
         3         13          3        333
                               5        555

4 rows selected.
```

что эквивалентно *ANSI* `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SQL> select * from a full outer join b on a.id = b.id;

        ID       COL1         ID       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         11          1        111
         3         13          3        333
                               5        555
         2         12

4 rows selected.
```